# What is the best way to replace Tuple<T1,T2> with C# 2

Tags: c#-2.0, tuples

I want to use a Tuple but in C# 2, it does not exist. I think to replace it by KeyValuePair.

Is it the best way to do this ?

Comment: Do you need the class to be generic, or do you know what types are going to be used?

Comment: Types are known, it's int for T1 and T2. So the alternative solution is an int[,] array but I don't want to lose the IEnumerable abilities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple class holding two generic members is probably the best option. This is essentially what `Tuple<T1,T2>` is.

If you know the types you are using, it is better to create a class with members of those types - this way you can use good naming for the class and members to ensure good readability (which a generic type like `Tuple` obscures).

---

From you comment, I would suggest that creating a small wrapper class (or possibly struct) to hold the `int` values will be the best choice.

Untested:

```
public class Point
{
   public Point(int xPos, int yPos)
   {
     this.xPos = xPos;
     this.yPos = yPos;
   }

   int xPos;
   int yPos;

   public int XPos { get { return xPos;} set { xPos = value;} }
   public int YPos { get { return yPos;} set { yPos = value;} }
}
```

Comment: So, using KeyValuePair<k,v> is a bad idea ?

Comment: @Florian - It just obscures meaning. If you need to use it in a _very_ limited way and meaning is not important, go ahead with KVP.

Answer (score 1):

If you use your `Tuple` always like `Tuple<T1,T2>` then you can switch easily to `KeyValuePair<T1,T2>` with no problems.

The only difference is that you have to use the `Key` and `Value` properties instead of the `ItemN` property of the `Tuple`.